# How do I select city, date and zip as separate value in a table that stores them as one value?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Please see the SQLFiddle example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/abd6d/1

here are a few example address:

MINNEAPOLIS MN 55450

MINNAPOLIS MN 55439-8136

BETHANY OK 73008

Hillsboro Oregon 97124

Not all of them are separated by spaces, but enough that I I think that is the method I want to approach.

running Oracle 11g

update:

this was how it was accomplished:

```
select bill_address4, Substr(bill_address4, 1, Instr(bill_address4, 
',') - 1) "CITY EXMP ONE",
regexp_substr(bill_address4,'[^,]+', 1, 1) "CITY EXMP TWO",
Trim(regexp_substr(bill_address4,'[^,]+', 1, 2)) "STATE/ZIP",
TRIM(regexp_substr(Trim(regexp_substr(bill_address4,'[^,]+', 1, 
2)),'[^ ]+', 1, 1)) "STATE",
TRIM(TRIM(regexp_substr(Trim(regexp_substr(bill_address4,'[^,]+', 
1, 2)),'[^ ]+',1,2))||' 
'||TRIM(regexp_substr(Trim(regexp_substr(bill_address4,'[^,]+', 1, 
2)),'[^ ]+',1,3))||' 
'||TRIM(regexp_substr(Trim(regexp_substr(bill_address4,'[^,]+', 1, 
2)),'[^ ]+',1,4))) "ZIP" from so_header
```

Comment: regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is easily feasible by sql. You will need to rearrange the raw data and the table schema by adding more columns.
The appraoch I recommand is string manipulation by using other programming language, for example, C#.

Answer (score 0):

See if such an approach helps.

- `TEMP` CTE finds position of the first digit in `citystatezip` column
- `zip`: that's the substring that starts from the `zip_position`
- `state`: nested functions

  - `substr` selects everything up to the `zip_position` (e.g. "SNOHOMISH WA ")
  - `trim` removes trailing spaces
  - `regexp_substr` extracts the last *word* from that substring (e.g. "WA")
- `city`: substring from the 1st character, up to position of the second space character starting from the back of the string (see `instr`'s parameters)

For sample data you posted (LA added), that would look as follows:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select p.*,
  3       regexp_instr(citystatezip, '\d') zip_position
  4     from po_header p
  5    )
  6  select t.po_number, t.customer, t.citystatezip,
  7    substr(t.citystatezip, t.zip_position) zip,
  8    regexp_substr(trim(substr(t.citystatezip, 1, t.zip_position - 1)), '\w+$') state,
  9    trim(substr(t.citystatezip, 1, instr(t.citystatezip, ' ', -1, 2))) city
 10  from temp t;

 PO_NUMBER CUSTOME CITYSTATEZIP                   ZIP        STATE      CITY
---------- ------- ------------------------------ ---------- ---------- -----------
         1 John    SNOHOMISH WA 98290             98290      WA         SNOHOMISH
         2 Jen     MINNAPOLIS MN 55439-8136       55439-8136 MN         MINNAPOLIS
         3 Jillian BETHANY OK 73008               73008      OK         BETHANY
         4 Jordan  Hillsboro Oregon 97124         97124      Oregon     Hillsboro
         5 Scott   Los Angeles CA 12345           12345      CA         Los Angeles

SQL>
```

Is it *perfect*? Certainly not, but the final solution depends on much more sample data. Generally speaking, data model is just wrong - you should have split those information into separate columns in the first place.